# Toggle menu bootstrap filled the entire screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I don't know if this is possible, or if it is, then I'm very dumb.

So I'm using bootstrap 4 to make my wordpress theme. I would like to make the menu to never expand so it always showing the hamburger icon. Now, when the user click it, I'd like it to filled the entire screen like in this website [www.tomango.co.uk](http://www.tomango.co.uk/).

I tried setting the  width to 100%, nothing happens. Changing it to a set px also change the toggle button icon.

If you know how to do this, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, please follow this...Just click on slide down, same as your requirement

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp